# CSS current class not being removed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following menu and I am trying to set a current class according to the url but it is not working, would anyone know why or even a better way of achieving this, thanks: 
HTML-

```
 <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a id="home" href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="hospitals" href="/hca-hospitals">HCA Hospitals</a>
                            <ul class="sub_menu">
                                <li id="one"><a  href="/hca-hospitals/hospitals-and-outpatients">Hospitals and Outpatients</a></li>
                                <li id="two"><a  href="/hca-hospitals/treatments">Treatments</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="benefits" href="/platinum-choice-benefits">Platinum Choice Benefits</a>
                            <ul class="sub_menu">
                                <li id="one"><a href="/platinum-choice-benefits/download-voucher">Download Voucher</a></li>
                                <li id="two"><a href="/platinum-choice-benefits/where-you-can-go">Where you can go</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="find" href="/find-a-hca-consultant">Find a Consultant</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="contact" href="/contact-hca">Contact</a>
                        </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS -

```
ul.dropdown li a.current  { color: #66c2c0;}
```

JQuery -

```
  var pathname = $(location).attr('href');

       if (pathname = "/contact-hca") {
            $("ul.dropdown li a#contact").addClass("current");
           $("ul.dropdown li a#find").removeClass("current");
        }
       if (pathname = "/find-a-hca-consultant") {
           $("ul.dropdown li a#find").addClass("current");
           $("ul.dropdown li a#contact").removeClass("current");
       }
```

Comment: use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: `ipathname = "/contact-hca"` this will always be true as you're using a setter not a comparison. See the comment above by @Satpal

Comment: Also `id` is unique, you need to use `class` instead for your list items.

Comment: You should probably consider an **else{}** just in case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Youare using `=` instead of `===`, which actually assigning `pathname`, not comparing it. Fix this.

```
if (pathname === "/contact-hca") {
  $("ul.dropdown li a#contact").addClass("current");
  $("ul.dropdown li a#find").removeClass("current");
} else if (pathname === "/find-a-hca-consultant") {
  $("ul.dropdown li a#find").addClass("current");
  $("ul.dropdown li a#contact").removeClass("current");
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as I have sub pages too -   var pathname = window.location.pathname;

 if (pathname.indexOf("find-a-hca-consultant") > 0) {
 
        $("ul.dropdown li a#find").addClass("current");
     
    }
    else if (pathname.indexOf("contact-hca") > 0){ 
     
           $("ul.dropdown li a#contact").addClass("current");   
    }

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you're using `if (pathname = "/contact-hca")`, which is wrong, because `=` stands for value assignment, and you want to compare equality of values, which is `==` or `===`. I would recommend you to use latter, because it's faster and it's literal comparison, and it works more robust, for example:

```
5 == '5'  // true
5 === '5' // false
```

So you should change your code with following:

```
var pathname = $(location).attr('href');

if (pathname === "/contact-hca") {
    $("ul.dropdown li a#contact").addClass("current");
    $("ul.dropdown li a#find").removeClass("current");
}
if (pathname === "/find-a-hca-consultant") {
    $("ul.dropdown li a#find").addClass("current");
    $("ul.dropdown li a#contact").removeClass("current");
}
```

Also, I would recommend you to learn how to use developer's console (every browser has it's own), which will help you determine what and where is the problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks guys but I couldnt get this to work, there must be another problem somewhere else.

Comment: I could not get this to work as pathname was returning the full url and not just the bit after the domain, thanks for everones great help!

Comment: Thanks maremp developer console is a blessing that I do not use enough of :-)

Comment: I know how you feel, I was the same when I first discovered the power of it. Btw, if you're using chrome, there's a plugin called JavaScript Errors Notifier, it puts a red exclamation mark right in your address field so you can see there was an error right away, in case you forget to check developer's console.